# Calendar Issues -Office 365

Tags: calendar, redirect

I have a calendar on my SharePoint homepage and I have added events to it.

My issue is that when you look at the calendar from the homepage, you do not see any of the events I created. You have to click on the calendar title which directs you to a new page where you are able to see them.

How do I fix this? I want to be able to see the events I have added without needing to click on the calendar title.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the view has a Filter, someone might have customized it. Click *Edit View* in the ribbon, scroll down to the *Filter* section and remove any unwanted filters.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I just tried that and it doesn't appear to have any filters currently on it. I appreciate the tip!

Comment: Hmm, then I have no idea what else could cause that. Have you tried to recreate the view? Or what happens when you add a View to another page than the home page?